# Install certificates on Wyse thin client (Windows 10 IoT)

Tags: windows-10, certificate, trusted-root-certificates, iot, windows-iot-core

We have a few Dell Wyse 5070 thin clients in our estate with no central management. They're running a version of Windows 10 IoT and appear to be mostly non-persistent.

Any changes I make to the machines get wiped out on reboot, unless I make them using the WyseEasySetupAdmin tool... but the options are limited in this tool. I'm assuming there may be another tool I can use but I'm struggling to find it.

I have a trusted root CA certificate that I need to install onto these machines. Normally we deploy this with GPO, but as these thin clients are not domain joined, I can't do that.

If I install the certificate manually through either IE or the Certificates MMC snap-in, it gets wiped out on reboot.

Searching Google and the Dell knowledge base, I'm finding info on certificates when using Wyse ThinOS, but none of this appears to apply to Windows 10 IoT. The menu options and/or folders just don't exist on this machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I may be able to install a trusted root CA onto this Windows 10 IoT based Wyse terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After spending ages researching it and deciding to post, I've actually worked it out rather quickly myself!

There is a utility called the Dell Wyse Unified Write Filter which is installed onto the thin clients. Logging in as "Admin", there is an icon on the desktop "Dell Wyse WF Disable". Double click this and the machine reboots. You can now write to the machine as you wish which allows me to install the certificate. Then double click "Dell Wyse WF Enable" to re-enable the filter.